# Why my image doesn't respect its parent's (section) padding

Tags: image, css, padding

I have a strange situation with an image and a section. You can download html, css and img1 from my [github](https://github.com/ttitto/TelerikAcademy/tree/master/HTMLCSS/Homeworks/CSSLayoutHW/Ex03MusicCategories)

The situation: I have a section tag which has padding:15px from all sides. In the section I have an img, floated left, then a p and a span with two buttons. The section has also a border and margin:35px
My problem: The image doesn't respect the section's bottom padding and goes through the sections bottom border.
I tried to put the img in a div inside the section, and also tried to give a height value for the section and 100% for the image's height but it didn't change anything

**What is the best solution for this problem, so that the picture takes all the height of the section respecting the section's top, left and bottom paddings?**

In the github, one step back, is a ppt-file TASKS.ppt. The third slide is what I try to achieve.
EDIT: Since code is requested, here it is:
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Music categories</title>
    <link href="Ex03MusicCategories.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Music Categories</h1>
    </header>
    <section>
        <img src="img1.png" />
        <div>
            <p>Even more websites all about website templates on <span>Just Web Templates</span> .</p>
            <span>
                <input type="button" value="Listen" />
                <input type="button" value="Add" />
            </span>
        </div>

    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #EEE;
    padding-top: 14px;
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}

    body header h1 {
        font-weight: lighter;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        font-family: Arial;
        letter-spacing: -2px;
    }

section {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #989898;
    border-width: 2px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 35px 0px;
}

    section img {
        float: left;
    }

        section img:after {
            clear: both;
        }
```

image [img1.png](https://github.com/ttitto/TelerikAcademy/blob/master/HTMLCSS/Homeworks/CSSLayoutHW/Ex03MusicCategories/img1.png)

Comment: Instead of providing links provide your code and image here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic, search for `clearfix`. One possible solution is

```css
section {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LHR9y/)

*Update:*

There's an article about CSS `float` and `clear` at [CSS-Tricks - All About Floats](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/).

Essentially, you need `clear`, when

- an element should stay *below* a floated element

and some clearfix, when

- the parent of a floated element collapses and you want the parent wrap around/include the floated children

You can also look at Stackoverflow [css-float tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/css-float/info) (an alias of [css-clear](/questions/tagged/css-clear)) or [clearfix](/questions/tagged/clearfix)

Comment: Vielen Dank! I know about clearfix, but I couldn't understand in which cases it is needed.